# Will a Windows bug check (BSOD) turn on the monitor?

Tags: winapi

I am working on a Windows Embedded Standard 2009 project deploying on an Atom powered tablet.  We have some known Windows bug check crashes (BSOD) that I am working through.  We also have a bug where the tablet becomes unresponsive with the screen off; requireing a hard power cycle to recover.  I am pursuing a theory that the unresponsive tablet is a BSOD crash that happened with the screen off.  We have EWF turned on which prevents a memory dump from writing to know if a BSOD occurred.  We turn the monitor off after user inactivity using user32.dll `SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF)`.

Will a Windows bug check (BSOD) turn on the monitor if it was turned off previously programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: [Yes it is.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542247.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bug checks do not turn on the monitor (doesn't matter if it went to sleep due to inactivity or your message).

Your best bet is to leave a kernel debugger attached.

Answer (score 2):

Can't speak for tablets, but the bug check isn't going to jump into a long series of power maangement routines, just to output the fact that it's exploded. The bug check does as little as is physically possible, since once you're in BSOD mode, the system is by definition already crashed and not stable and in a highly unknown state. Starting to call other complicated subsytems is not going to happen, as the BSOD may very well have happened in the very routine(s) it's trying to call.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  That was my hunch but wanted to see if anyone definitively knew.

Answer (score 1):

While bugcheck does not go through any power management code, it does make operations that would usually wake a monitor up.  Bug-check changes screen resolution and switches to text-mode.   If you have a kernel-debugger attached (or just configured), the system waits for the kernel debugger response and will not display the blue-screen text until you hit "g".

In the default configuration it will also attempt to create a crash-dump and reboot.  If you suspect a bugcheck look for memroy.dmp in the windows directory or connect a kernel debugger.

Comment: EWF ensures that all disk writes are redirected to RAMDISK, so they disappear at reboot.